# Konversations runs Akonadi migration on every startup

Tags: kde, akonadi

Every time I start konversation, I get this screen:

[image]

It takes some 15 seconds …

How can I prevent it from coming up? I mean migrating once should be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open , upstream, kde bug

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=287673

> Akonadi is invoked indirectly by the KDE PIM libraries, which Konversation uses
>   for integration with the KDE address book. This integration currently cannot be
>   disabled (although we're currently planning to change that).

For now, the only "work around" is to disable akonadi and use an alternate application (to konversation).

**Note: disabling akonadi affects KAddressbook, Kmail, Kontact, KOrganizer, Konversation, Kopete, and any Widgets using these applications.**

### Disable akonadi

Edit `~/.config/akonadi/akonadiserverrc`

```
kate ~/.config/akonadi/akonadiserverrc
```

And change `StartServer=true` to

```
[%General]
Driver=QMYSQL

[QMYSQL]
Name=akonadi
Host=
Options="UNIX_SOCKET=/home/your_user/.local/share/akonadi/socket-ufbt/mysql.socket"
ServerPath=/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi
StartServer=false

[Debug]
Tracer=null
```

Log out and back in or stop akonadi with

```
akonadictl stop
```

You can manually start akonadi with

```
akonadictl start
```

Un-do the edit to re-enable.

[image: config]

See also : http://ubuntuku.org/16/how-to-disable-nepomuk-akonadi/

Comment: Thanks. Those bungled, communicating applications seem to be a double edged sword …